# Partial component from URL in Swift

Tags: swift

I have this URL:

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/182BB05D-E460-42CD-9030-EBD907799E0F/Documents/video/f9cf9f593a3f50c9ee50acb51aaeee1ee1febbe3c2cd4aded49b39e01b42f9ac/6B617D7C-F153-4F7C-BE02-4362CAC4A4C9.mov

And I want to get just this string back from the URL

> video/f9cf9f593a3f50c9ee50acb51aaeee1ee1febbe3c2cd4aded49b39e01b42f9ac/6B617D7C-F153-4F7C-BE02-4362CAC4A4C9.mov

Is using pathComponents the only way?

Comment: You need to removed static document path, Am I correct?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the documents directory path and remove it from your video file path.

Example :

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
let videoPath = "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/182BB05D-E460-42CD-9030-EBD907799E0F/Documents/video/f9cf9f593a3f50c9ee50acb51aaeee1ee1febbe3c2cd4aded49b39e01b42f9ac/6B617D7C-F153-4F7C-BE02-4362CAC4A4C9.mov"

videoPath.replacingOccurrences(of: documentsPath, with: "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
var filePath = "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/182BB05D-E460-42CD-9030-EBD907799E0F/Documents/video/f9cf9f593a3f50c9ee50acb51aaeee1ee1febbe3c2cd4aded49b39e01b42f9ac/6B617D7C-F153-4F7C-BE02-4362CAC4A4C9.mov"

if let range = filePath.range(of: "video")?.lowerBound {
    let url = filePath.substring(from: range)
}
```